# Why am I getting undefined error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

the syntax seems to be correct, I dont get it, here is 
error: app.js:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: getBirthyear is not defined
Code:

```
const person = {
  name: 'Tommy',
  age: 32,
  location: {
    state: 'Missouri',
    city: 'louisisana',
    street: '1 marcia drive',
    job: 'web dev'
  },
   getBirthyear: function() {
    return 2018 - this.age;
  }
}
let val;
val = getBirthyear();
document.write(val);
```

Comment: You've defined "getBirthyear" as a property of the "person" object, right? So you have to reference it via that object.

Comment: thank you, wow i feel stupid, I was thinking that error was telling me that getBirthyear was not defined, I didnt realize it was telling me I was refferencing it wrong, newbie mistakes, thanks for the help. Where can I find resources that explain errors in depth, this way I can understand the errors, and not spam SO with such questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it by using `person.getBirthday()` since it is a property of `person`